# How to update an existing table in SQL Server from R?

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to update an existing table in SQL Server (`IndicatorOutput`), but I am getting an error. My table has exactly the same column names and format. Below is the code that I have been using:

```r
library(RODBC)
DB_DW <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername;
                           database=dbname;trusted_connection=true')
Sql_IndicatorOutput <- "SELECT * FROM dbo.IndicatorOutput"
DF_Ind_output <- sqlQuery(DB_DW, Sql_IndicatorOutput)
sqlSave(DB_DW, DF_Ind_output, tablename = "IndicatorOutput",
        rownames = FALSE, append = TRUE )
```

Comment: What error are you getting? We can't help if you don't give us that information (esp since we don't have access to your database to try it ourselves). (Since your code isn't changing anything, does it have something to do with duplicate ids/keys?)

Comment: fair enough, this is the error I get:Error in sqlSave(DB_DW, DF_Ind_output, tablename = "IndicatorOutput",  : 
  unable to append to table ‘IndicatorOutput’

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/59b0b93bd4947eb7c2c0223b0b45d56bc928d912/R/sql.R#L220), it looks as if the only way to get more information is to do `sqlSave(..., verbose=TRUE)`.